# Parent object to mirrored side of object

Tags: modifiers, objects, mirror, parent

I am trying to make an animated short film with Blender. I need to parent an object to the mirrored side of another object. Do anyone know how to do that?

**Here is an an example**

The cube on the left is a mirror of the cube at the right. The mirror object (the center of the mirror) is the big flat cube. I want to parent the monkey to the cube at the left. The cubes need to be animated. So I can not parent the monkey to the cube at the right. I hope it makes sense.

[image: Simple example of the problem.]

Comment: Hello. Can you add more details (a picture) of the mirrored object? Also, what do you mean by "parent" in this context?

Comment: Now I have added an example of what I mean.

Comment: By "parent" I mean follow the mirrored side of the object.

Comment: ok, thanks for the edit, though why don't you invert all that: you can have the same result if the original cube was on the left

Comment: The reason why is, that I want to "parent" objects to both the left and the richt cube. I should have written that in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can be done with some constraints:

[image]

Place an empty has child of the original cube. This is to place Suzanne relatively to the cube.

Then add two *"transformation"* constraints to Suzanne, with the above empty as target.

[image]

Presuming the mirror is on X.

One constraint for the locations, inverting X source (maps -1/1 to 1/-1).

One constraint for the rotations, inverting Y and Z source either (the same way).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.